# Updating a service without interruption

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, .net-4.0

I have for the first time the need to update a service without any interruption. So far i had to stop the application on IIS then replace the files and then restart the application. I need to be able to hot swap this service for a new one on the fly. I will only need to add new methods or correct code inside existing one. In no way i will ever change the currently existing methods parameters. If need be i'll create brand new methods and my app will slowly be changed to point to new one.

My problem right now is that service uses other services and together they form a very high security system and if i stop that service for more than 8 seconds every people using the applications at the moment are getting kicked out. Other services internally do communicate within the network with that service as well for authentication for every single action a user perform on any of our applications. So we have WAN and LAN calls. Since it's a 3 step authentication (maybe 4 later one if we integrate federated credentials) and if one is off everything cut off.

I was wondering if there is a solution to that ?

I was thinking of a front service with connection to 2 services. One being the Live Service and the other the backup. when i wan to update i cut the Live and the front end will detect no connection on Live service and will fall on the backup one. Then i replace the live and put it online again and the front end will start to read the live again. Couple hours later i can replace the Backup with a copy of the live for the next update.
Anyhow this still cause me the problem that the front end would need implementation of the new service each time.

Comment: To wit you will not be able to do a hot deploy without any interruption. At the very least you will need to cycle the App Pool that your target service is in after you deploy updated files.

Comment: thanks but i'll try @davidb tip first. shutting down an app pool is very slow compare to an IIS redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an identical application and redirect users to this by using a DNS change or a simple redirection in IIS before you make a change.

You mention internal users suggesting that the app is only used internally? If so you could force a DNS change on your domain/network to the new app and they will never know the difference. In the meantime make the change to your 'live' app and then do the reverse DNS change back again.

Failing that you could always perform the change out of hours. Every application requires a maintenance window every now and then.

Comment: This service is also external. I have 2 WCF accessible from the outside and 1 WCF internally that only those 2 external WCF can speak too and is used to prevent any communication between those 2 to go out and be tampered with. these 2 services are timed to match and ensure best security possible at low performance cost. encryption is done internally and the routing back and forth of the information is changing every time and new encryption key are being use each ~8sec. Out of the hour with international apps is difficult,but IIS redirect seems like a good fallback idea. I'll take look into it.

Comment: ok this works perfectly. there is even commands for doing it easily such as `AppCmd.exe set vdir "[APPLICATION NAME]" -physicalPath:"[NEW PATH]"` the change happen in less than 0.02 seconds so that's rather fast. a simple secondary call for each function on fail will be enough for the few that will still fail. Anyway most calls are as fast as 0.05 sec so there shouldn't be too much errors.

Answer (score 0):

The only chance to achieve this (so i think) is the following:

You keep all your logic (which will be updated) in a separate library, which is dynamically loaded (and unloaded [keyword: separate AppDomain]!!). So for (bad) example, you could reload this assembly each time you call a method. This way cou could replace this dll on the fly without having to stop the service.

But this also has some disadvantages: For example this will slow down performance. Further you will have to implement your own security checks (that no malicious hacker, cracker or whatever can replace your library with one containing dangerous code.

Unfortunately this is the only alternative I'm aware of. I hope this could help you a little bit.

Comment: Making a DLL doesn't help me as the front end service will need a new WSDL to expose the new methods so i need to update him as well. I have been looking at Azure for a while and i wonder if they do have a hot swap feature. If i can hot swap RAM on my server i don't see why i couldn't with a service you know !

Comment: Oh, sorry. I did not realize that you are not talking about a windows service. Unfortunately I never worked with .net web technologies that much.

Comment: no worry, WCF service are now .DLL files too and are just exposed through IIS. it's now magical, no need for register.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Think I will look into this soon.

Comment: I think I 'accidentally' found another solution that may fit for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx Maybe it helps.

Comment: you need shadow copy enabled on the server, i thought of that but the IT manager here don't want to allow this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could use WebDeploy - it will do everything for you quicker than you can do it by hand. It will still stop the application then swap the files out and then start the application again but in most cases when I've done this nobody has ever noticed (admittedly not a busy service)

Comment: will take a loo, but ya just internally with 10-15 selected users for that new service i get easily 2-3 request per seconds. right now i have only 1 app with that service hook to it but when i get all my apps and all our pool of users roughly 150-200 concurrent connections. it will probably be problematic. will check anyhow thanks.